# Bootstrap navbar not inline (sorry I'm learning)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>#</title>

     <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="css/dancepartner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
     <div class="row">  
       <img class="col-m-3 logo" src="images/logo.png" alt= "Dance Partner.com" >
       <ul class="inline col-m-9">
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="signup.php">Join Now</a></li>
          <form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form" action="signin.php">
            <div class="form-group" "login-box">
               <label class=""> Username: </label>
                 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Email">
               <label class=""> Password: </label> 
                 <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
               <input type="submit" value="Sign In "></li>
             </div>
           </form>  
         </ul>
       </div> 
     </nav> 
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

So there's my code and I'm running the latest full version of bootstrap.  The logo img is the only thing that is in the right spot, but the home/about/join now links are right below the logo and the user login in right below that.  Please help because I've looked everywhere first.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<form>` as a child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: make a fiddle of your code

Comment: @surajrawat some one who is just learning may not know about http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @JonP he will get to know after searching at some point he has to start using it so why not today !